# links without http: like //code.jquery.com/etc

Tags: http, web, hyperlink, protocols

Lately I've noticed that some sites (such as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) and some widgets such pinterest feed widget, and many others.

They started to use links in the format

- *`//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`*
- *`//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js`*

  1. what does the `//` means ?
  2. is it the same as `http` ?
  3. if `//` is the same as `http` why using it instead of http ?
  4. if both are different, can I use it to link my website ?

*as addition: I'm not sure, but I think I've seem some use `//name:sub.domaine.com`, am I wrong ? if those exist, what do they mean ?*

#### Edit:

as explained in an answer bellow, I can use the `//` notation to make my links shorter, but when I use it for my website: **Chrome** changes the link to: *`file:///`* which is not what I expected

Comment: Usually, they add the protocol later (perhaps in a base tag) in order to avoid changing all the links from http to https or vice versa depending on the current protocol, this seems be a technique to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a *protocol-relative* URL. If the page which includes it uses HTTP, then it's HTTP. If the page which includes it uses HTTPS, then it uses HTTPS.

This is convenient so that you can ensure that you don't fetch insecure resources in a secure page (this causes the "mixed content" warning you might have seen), without bothering with the overhead of SSL/TLS in a page which is delivered unencrypted anyhow.

It's similar to how URLs beginning with a single `/` are resolved relative to the current protocol and hostname, and URLs with no leading `/` or scheme are resolved relative to the current page's directory.

Answer (score -4):

To keep it simple: most web browsers now do not require the full [http://www] anymore.  So yes, to be cool and to keep the URL's short, you can skip the full [http://www.] and just use //

Comment: "to be cool and to keep the URL's short" that is not really the reason wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Really? Just type in //yahoo.com or whatever site you want and see if the link works (it will).  Bottom line is that it works and thus why it is so popular on mobile apps, it saves a lot of space in the blog world of 250 chars limits.

Comment: @TimSamandari, I tried `//yahoo.com` on my web browser (Chrome: 26.0.1410.43) and I get redirected to: `file:///yahoo.com`