# Why can't I load jQuery from a local file?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I just have this line in a local .html file:

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As is standard to load Google's jQuery.

But the get request just fails...chrome console just shows little red x with:

```
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

:( What's going wrong?

Comment: you missed `:` in `http://`

Comment: It's not unusual to leave off http and use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692601/links-without-http-like-code-jquery-com-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad URL, it's missing the colon (:) in `http://`.

This is likely from using the shorthand `src="//ajax.googleapis.com...`.  Browsers will prepend the `//` with the correct scheme--`http:` or `https:`, however since you're accessing it locally it's prepending a `file:` scheme--which expects the resource to be on your local drive.

For local dev use the fully qualified URL with a specified scheme, or use a local webserver so that you can access the document using the `http` or `https` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 ^
```

As mentioned, you could just use:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ....oh. I copied the link from their repo....thought it would be right. Don't know why they left out the `http`...https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: @Aerovistae: They're using a protocol-relative URL.

Comment: @Aerovistae - if you leave off the protocol, then it will work for HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @KarlAnderson But it won't work for file:// (open html doc on local pc, without web server)